# How to revert to original gnome shell theme

Tags: gnome, themes

I'm on 12.04 and it seems my gnome shell theme went corrupted in its .js and .css files. How to reveert to the original and default theme? Is there a place where it can be downloaded or maybe it's enough to purge and reinstall certain packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

- Login to Gnome Classic
- Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open terminal and run following commands:

  ```
  sudo apt-get autoremove --purge gnome-themes-standard
  sudo apt-get install gnome-themes-standard
  ```
- Log back into Gnome Shell.

Comment: Unfortunately that packages does not contain the files needed for shell theme.

Comment: Try to use some custom themes using gnome-tweak-tool and then try to set the default one.

Comment: This won't work, as the default files were already been edited.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the first suggestion works with the master package:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge gnome-shell
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

Thanks and cheers!